# Merge commit in detached state

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say, I have the following commit in master branch.

```
-> step-4
-> step-3
-> step-2
-> step-1
-> step-0
```

And then I switched temporarily to step-0 via `git checkout <step-0-sha>`. 
Now what I want is to add a single file say `newfile.txt` to that commit. I saw other questions on rebasing and cherry picking, but that doesn't solve the problem. 
Here the problem is that this `newfile.txt` (and some other files) is already committed in other commits (steps). But I also want in `step-0` commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### option 1

You can use these commands to meet your requirements:

```
git checkout <commit for step-0>
touch newfile.txt
git add .
git commit --amend -am 'info'
git rebase --onto HEAD <commit for step-0> master
```

#### option 2

```
git rebase -i master~5
```

Input <kbd>i</kbd> to change `pick <commit for step-0>` to `edit <commit for step-0>`, and then input <kbd>Esc</kbd> and `:wq`.

During the rebase:

```
touch newfile.txt 
git add .
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Yes, it will rebase the commit from `step-1` to `step-4` to your current HEAD and named it as `master`.

Comment: And I added another option for you to refer.